# "We have always helped each other" vs. "We always help each other"

Tags: meaning-in-context, present-perfect

We have always helped each other and we’ll keep helping each other

We always help each other and we’ll keep helping each other

What’s the difference ?
Are both of them correct?

Comment: The first sentence uses the Present Perfect (actions up to this point and relevant to the present), the second sentence uses the Present Simple (actions in general sense; general truth).

Answer (score 1):

> **We have always helped each other and we will keep helping each other**

We have always  started helping each other for some time  and we  will continue to do so in the future.

The present perfect says that activity  commenced in the past and is continuing up to the present moment.

> **We always help each other and we will keep helping each other**

It is our habit to always help each other and we will continue to do so in the future too.

The simple present talks about present habit or a  statement or fact.

Both  the sentences are correct.

Answer (score 1):

**We have always helped each other and we’ll keep helping each other**

The first part of the sentence refers to something that has occurred in the past up to this point in time. The second part of the sentence talks about a commitment into the future, from this point onwards.

**We always help each other and we will keep helping each other**

Here, the first part of the sentence refers to something that is accepted as true, something that happens all the time, past, present and *future*. This last detail being a relevant distinction to me. If you have doubts about that, note how "I always do X" is a perfectly good answer to the question "Will you do X?" while, "I have always done X" is more vague.

The second part of the sentence is the same as the above.

Now, while the genreal meaning of these two sentences will still be understood as the intended one, the latter can be seen as being a bit redundant (most of the time). Now redundancy isn't always bad, it can serve to add strength to an idea for instance, but in this case you may not want to use it unless it's a stylistic choice.